# How to place values inside table cell according to combination of table header and first row value?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

the below is my mysql table structure, the values inside are not fixed and can get changed by admin.

```
town_name | product_name| pending_quantity
------------------------------------------
 Jaipur   | Mobile      | 5
 Jaipur   | Charger     | 3
 Surat    | wallet      | 2
 Surat    | Mobile      | 1
 Surat    | battery     | 3
 Surat    | cover       | 2
```

In my php code, i stored all these values in 3 different arrays (one for each column) and everything is fine. I want to show this data in HTML table but the structure it needs to be shown is a problem to me. Below is the expected HTML table structure.

```
town_name | Mobile | charger | wallet | Battery | cover
-------------------------------------------------------
 Jaipur   | 5      | 3       |        |         |     
 Surat    | 1      |         |  2     |  3      | 2
```

So far, I've achieved to show rows and column headers the way it should be. But am now unable to put the pending quantity values in its place.

This is my php code if its of any help

```
<tbody>
                    <?php
                        $count = 1;
                        $row=0;
                        foreach($townid as $townKey=>$townValue) {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>$count</td>";
                            echo "<td>$townValue</td>";
                            foreach($items as $productKey=>$productValue) {
                                echo "<td>$pendingqty[$townKey]</td>";  
                                $row++;
                            }
                            $row++;
                            echo "</tr>";
                            $count++;
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

The column headers (mobile, charger etc etc) are dynamic and the town names are also dynamic. Please help me in achieving the desired result via mysql or html.

### PHP code that gets values inside arrays

```
$townid2 = array();
$itemname = array();
$pendingqty = array();
$items = array();
    
    $query = mysql_query("select o.town_id as townid, od.item_name as itemname, sum(od.pending_qnty) as pendingqty FROM tbl_order o JOIN tbl_order_data od on o.id = od.order_id where month(o.order_date)='1' GROUP BY o.town_id, od.item_name  ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $townid2[]=$row['townid'];
        $pendingqty[] = $row['pendingqty'];
        $items[] = $row['itemname']; 
    }
    
    $townid = array_unique($townid2, SORT_REGULAR); 

$query2 = mysql_query("select od.item_name FROM tbl_order_data od JOIN tbl_order o on o.id=od.order_id where od.order_id IN (select id from tbl_order where month(order_date)='1') group by od.item_name order by o.item_name ");
    $productArray = array();
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) { 
        $productArray[] = $row2['item_name'];
    }
```

Comment: would there ever be a case where you'd have duplicate rows in the database? e.g. two rows that are Jaipur, Charger, quantity?

Comment: also it'd be useful to see the code where you generate the arrays

Comment: Richard, answer to your first question is NO. because i need to show sum of pending quantities of a particular town of particular product.

Comment: the code to get values in array, its just mysql query with group function and sum function. Am editing my question to insert the php code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it (I'm using mysql_query because you did, but it's deprecated so you really should switch):

```
$things = array();
$columns = array('Mobile','charger','wallet','Battery','cover'); //this can/should be populated dynamically using a distinct product query, but I'm hard-coding it because I'm lazy
$query = mysql_query("select o.town_id as townid, od.item_name as itemname, sum(od.pending_qnty) as pendingqty FROM tbl_order o JOIN tbl_order_data od on o.id = od.order_id where month(o.order_date)='1' GROUP BY o.town_id, od.item_name");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $things[$row['townid']][$row['itemname']] = $row['pendingqty'];
}

... //whatever code until you're ready for the table

echo "<table><thead><tr>";
foreach($columns as $column){
    echo "<th>".$column."</th>";
}
echo "</tr><thead><tbody>";
foreach($things as $key=>$value){
    echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td>";
    foreach($columns as $column){
        echo "<td>".(isset($value[$column]) ? $value[$column] : null)."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks Richard. Am trying out this code. Will comment back if it works and hope it does. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just realized it's not going to work. Give me a second to update (that's what I get for trying to code while watching a movie!).

Comment: Awesome. Its working just like the way I wanted. You just saved me man. You're the hero !!! Thanks a lot Richard.

Comment: No problem. Just throw in a query to get all the distinct product names for the `$column` array, and switch to using mysqli or the PDO object and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take

```
$itemnames = array();
$pendingqtys = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT 
    od.item_name AS itemname
FROM
    tbl_order o
JOIN
    tbl_order_data od ON o.id = od.order_id
WHERE
    MONTH(o.order_date) = '1'
GROUP BY o.town_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $itemnames[] = $row['itemname'];
}

$query = null;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  
    o.town_id AS townid, 
    od.item_name AS itemname, 
    SUM(od.pending_qnty) AS pendingqty 
FROM 
    tbl_order o 
        JOIN 
    tbl_order_data od ON o.id = od.order_id 
WHERE
    MONTH(o.order_date) = '1' 
GROUP BY o.town_id , od.item_name");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pendingqtys[$row['townid']][$row['itemname']]=$row['pendingqty'];
}
```

Then to display the results

```
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>Town Names</th>";
    foreach($itemnames as $itemname){
        echo "<th>".$itemname."</th>";
    }
echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
    foreach ($pendingqtys as $town => $pendingqty){
        echo "<tr><th>".$town."</th>";
        foreach ($itemnames as $itemname){
            echo "<td>".$pendingqty[$itemname]."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try :)

Comment: just noticed a typo  `$pendingqtys[$row['town_name']][$row['product_name']]=$row['pending_quantity'];` should be  `$pendingqtys[$row['townid']][$row['itemname']]=$row['pendingqty'];`